# "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#

```
        class Cell:Button
        {
        public bool Presence { get; set; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cell[,] cells = new Cell[10, 10];
            
        foreach (var item in cells)
        {
        item.Presence = true;//тут ловлю Exeption "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
                //item.Height = 5;
                //item.Width = 5;
                //item.Background = Brushes.Gray;
                //item.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: В том, что `item` у вас `null`. Когда вы создаете коллекцию ссылочных типов, то по умолчанию она заполняется значениями `null`. Вам надо эти `Cell` создать через `new Cell()`, но вы цикле `foreach` не получится, попробуйте 2 цикла `for` и присваивайте по индексам `cells[i, j] = new Cell();`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Но, честно говоря, не видел еще такую реализацию.

Comment: Может быть есть иной способ создания двумерного массива ссылочного типа...
Моя задача в следующем. 
Я создаю класс - ячейка. Далее в другом классе я создаю двумерный массив таких ячеек, получая некое поле, которое буду заполнять данными и впоследствии работать с ними.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, вы можете задать его отдельно.